# Is this correct: "Jon had gotten up early"?

Tags: american-english, past-participles, dialect

I've decided to start [a blog](http://2200ce.wordpress.com/) (for the first time).

> Ah! I forgot to tell why Jon had **gotten** up early.

I've never used the word “gotten” nor have I seen anyone use it, but it seems that my usage of that word is correct in the sentence above. If not, please tell me how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

Per [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gotten):

> **gotten**: *Past participle of get*.
>
> **Usage**
>
> As past participles of get, got and gotten both date back to Middle
>   English. The form gotten is not used in British English but is very
>   common in North American English, though even there it is often
>   regarded as non-standard. In North American English, *got* and
>   *gotten* are not identical in use. ***Gotten*** usually implies the process of obtaining something, as in *he had gotten us tickets for
>   the show*, while **got** implies the state of possession or ownership,
>   as in *I haven’t got any money*.

So, the usage of "*gotten up*" in your sentence is **correct**, though **informal**. As is indicated by the presence of this phrase found in numerical blogs online, like [this](http://pyroteapot.tumblr.com/post/58045423545/this-is-the-first-time-ive-gotten-up-early-of-my) and [this](http://www.pinterest.com/pin/163607398935756194/).

Answer (score 1):

I remember back in school, in English class, we were forbidden from using the word 'got' in writing because it tends to be a rather colourless and lazy word. Avoid this problem by substituting more interesting alternatives.

Jon arose early that day.... Jon awoke early... etc etc etc